# Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double

Tags: php, double

I am getting `Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double error` on my code

```
$tbl->addRow();
$tbl->addCell($name);
$tbl->addCell('$' . number_format(doubleval($price), 2,',', ' ') );
```

I know the $price is a value 15,00 which is a number. How could it be fixed?

Comment: You sure that price is not "$15,00" but is actually 15,00?

Comment: Try to add `var_dump($price); var_dump(doubleval($price))` before this line. Check the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible doubleval() is returning some sort of error because the number "15,00" is in european format instead of the standard. Have you tried using "15.00" instead?